# how to insert BIT values in MySQL using Java?

Tags: java, mysql

i am unable to add a Boolean value in Mysql how can i do so using java

i have to use QueryExecuter for this perpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean, you can't use the boolean type? otherwise you could just convert true to 1 and false to 0 and just use an integer field...

Comment: In MySQL BOOL is an alias for TINYINT, so it needs to be used just like integer would be. moon however seems to be asking about BIT type column.